# Deflate: safe size

Tags: deflate

I have a problem to find a safe way to create Blocks, it regards the lengths of huffman codes particularly.
Is there a safe numbers of bytes to read from data, for which the resulting huffman codes do not exceed the established length of 15 and also that the compression will not be that bad? The specification don't clarify how this condition is achieved.

At the moment what I was doing was to stop my input encoding up to a certain number of bytes because I have no idea how to handle this thing.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Limiting the length of the Huffman codes is not done by limiting the amount of data to compress in a block. That limit would be too short. Instead if applying the Huffman algorithm results in some codes longer than 15 bits, then the Huffman code is modified to fix the problem. See [trees.c in zlib](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/trees.c#L528) for an example.

It is also possible to use a modified Huffman algorithm that has a limit on the maximum code length. See [*A fast algorithm for optimal length-limited Huffman codes*](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=79147.79150).

Comment: I still have doubt to know when stopping the LZ77 algorithm and starting a new block. How does deflate handle this? I have read the link you sent me, but unfortunately it is actually difficult to understand for me, instead with the codes in tree.c I found good idea and for that I thank you

Comment: zlib's deflate emits a new block once a certain number of literal/length symbols have been accumulated. With the default settings, 16,384 symbols.

Comment: Hi Mark! I have just finished my compression/decompression algorithm regarding huffman dynamic block. I have tried to compress an image of 3.19 Mb and it took around 22 second to compress(on windows) and around 0.8 seconds to decompress it. The compression altough wasn't good, from 3.19 Mb to 3.09. Do you think all of those informations are reasonable? Probably the real compression will be real when I combine the algorithm with LZ77.

Comment: I have no way of knowing, since ability to compress depends entirely on the content. In particular of the 3.19 MB. Yes, you can't expect to get much out of just Huffman, but again that depends on the content. The times you quote are incredibly slow, but perhaps speed is not your objective.

Comment: Now I re-tested. 22 seconds turn into 0.34 sec if I don't consider the part of enconding the literals. Precisely I have a for in which I browse the buffer byte to byte encoding the literal found  until the size of the file. A multi-byte encoding would be a solution but don't know how.